# An issue with SSL or my misunderstanding of it

Tags: objective-c, ios, ssl

I got my crt from instantssl and I used the open ssl to make a .p12 java keytool to make me a java key-store.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt -in UTNAddTrustSGCCA.crt -in ComodoUTNSGCCA.crt -in EssentialSSLCA_2.crt -in www_geobomber_com.crt -inkey www.geobomber.com.key -out www.geobomber.com.p12


keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore www.thedomain.com.jks -srckeystore www.thedomain.com.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -alias 1
```

My iOS program for the SSL connection is as below. It all runs and seems to be fine. My first question is that ( NSDictionary *settings ) set up right? - is that all I need for a successful SSL connection. I was under the impression that I would need to have the crts on the iphone.

```
            CFReadStreamRef readStream;
            CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
            CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"www.thedomain.com", port, &readStream, &writeStream);


            NSInputStream *inputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSInputStream *)readStream;
            NSOutputStream *outputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
            [inputStream open];
            [outputStream open];


            BOOL    result = [inputStream    setProperty:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL forKey:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey];
            NSLog(@"inputStream result %i",result);
            result =[outputStream   setProperty:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL forKey:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey];
            NSLog(@"outputStream result %i",result);
            if (YES){
                NSDictionary *settings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredCertificates,
                                          [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot,
                                          [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain,
                                          kCFNull,kCFStreamSSLPeerName,
                                          nil];

                CFReadStreamSetProperty((CFReadStreamRef)inputStream, kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings, (CFTypeRef)settings);
                CFWriteStreamSetProperty((CFWriteStreamRef)outputStream, kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings, (CFTypeRef)settings);
            }
            //endstuff

            NSString *response  = @"hello from iphone stream";
            NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[response dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
            NSLog(@"going to try to write.");
            [outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your certificate is signed by a recognised CA you don't need to do anything to the client. The client should already trust recognised CAs.

Comment: Thanks that what I thought. Just when I did it with the java client it refused the connection.

Comment: @Andrew 'connection refused' is a TCP error, nothing to do with SSL.

Comment: the message wasnt as simple as refused. :) the was alot of SSL type of messages. + as a side note do you know of any examples of a SSL connection on macosx in c/c++ since openSSL is deprecated. Thank you.